# Trouble setting long value in singleton IOS

Tags: ios, singleton, long-integer

I'm having trouble with setting and accessing long properties on a Singleton object. Every time I try to access a long property it returns -1.

My singleton interface file is as follows:

```
 @interface gameData : NSObject <NSCoding>
    @property (assign, nonatomic) long score;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) long level;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) long riddlesCompleted;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) long hints;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) long firstLetters;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) long answers;

    +(instancetype)sharedGameData;
    -(void)reset;
    -(void)save;

  @end
```

Then the implementation file sets up the encoders and decoders as follows:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeDouble:self.score forKey:gameDataScoreKey];
    [aCoder encodeDouble:self.level forKey:gameDataLevelKey];
    [aCoder encodeDouble:self.riddlesCompleted forKey:gameDataRiddlesCompletedKey];
    [aCoder encodeDouble:self.hints forKey:gameDataHintsKey];
    [aCoder encodeDouble:self.firstLetters forKey:gameDataFirstLettersKey];
    [aCoder encodeDouble:self.answers forKey:gameDataAnswersKey];
}
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _score = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:gameDataScoreKey];
        _level = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:gameDataLevelKey];
        _riddlesCompleted = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:gameDataRiddlesCompletedKey];
        _hints = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:gameDataHintsKey];
        _firstLetters = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:gameDataFirstLettersKey];
        _answers = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey:gameDataAnswersKey];
    }
    return self;
}

+(instancetype) sharedGameData{
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Values are initialised as follows:

```
-(id)init{
    if(self = [super init]){
        _score = 500;
        _riddlesCompleted = 0;
        _level = 1;
        _hints = 3;
        _firstLetters = 3;
        _answers = 3;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and then the instance is loaded:

```
+(NSString*)filePath{
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
                    stringByAppendingString:@"gameData"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance{
    NSData* decodeData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[gameData filePath]];
    if (decodeData) {
        gameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodeData];
        return gameData;
    }
    return [[gameData alloc] init];
}
```

Then elsewhere in the application when I try to access these values I am not able to access the values of hints, firstletters or answers.

If I try logging the values as follows:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [gameData sharedGameData].score] );
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [gameData sharedGameData].hint] );
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [gameData sharedGameData].answers]);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [gameData sharedGameData].firstLetters]);
```

The output I get is 500 for score but for all the others I get 0 even though they are initialised in the gameData.m file with values 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess:
In loadInstance() you read the values from the file, so if there is a file you won't get in the init() where you set the values.

To be sure there is no gamedata-file you should reset the simulator oder delete the app from the device and try again.